# How to prove a set is norm-closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I have to prove that the given space is 'norm-closed convex.'

I proved the 'convex' part.

But I don't know how to prove a set is 'norm-closed'

I think I have to do the followings.

1. Let *X* be a normed space.

   Consider a convergent sequence {$x_n$} $\rightarrow x \in X$
2. Then show $||x_n - x|| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is **not** correct. Note that $x_n \to x$ implies always $$\|x_n-x\| \leq \epsilon$$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $\epsilon>0$; that's simply the definition of convergence of a sequence. If you want to show that a subspace $X \subseteq Y$ is closed, you have to show that for any convergent sequence $x_n \to x \in Y$ it holds that $x \in X$.

For example, if we take $X=(-1,1)$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$, then $X$ is not closed (in $Y$) since $x_n := 1-\frac{1}{n}$ satisfies $x_n \to 1 \in Y$, but $1 \notin X$.